# Existence of two independent random variables on a finite sample space.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

The sample space $\Omega$ contains five elements with positive probability. Are there two independent random variables on $\Omega$, each of which takes five different values?

---

My solution is the following. Suppose there are random variables $X$ and $Y$, each of which takes five different values. Let $\omega_0$ be one of the outcomes and $X(\omega_0) = x_0, Y(\omega_0) = y_0 $ and $\forall i X(\omega_i) \neq x_0, Y(\omega_i) \neq y_0 $. Then $P(x = x_0, y = y_0) = p $ and $P(x = x_0) \cdot P(y= y_0) = p^2 $. Therefore the independence criteria is not satisfied and the answer to question is no.

Is that a correct solution?

Comment: Well, they didn't say what are the probabilities and you assumed $1/5$.

Comment: I changed the probabilities to $p$ and $p^2$ respectively

Comment: I think that after the change you made the solution is correct and very similar to the one I was writing in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to assume that there exists $\omega\in \Omega$ with $0<\mathsf{P}(\{\omega\})<1$, where $\mathsf{P}$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,2^{\Omega})$ because for any injective functions $X,Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ (random variables taking distinct values for each $\omega$), $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Y)=2^{\Omega}$.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is answering the question in the affirmative or not. But I assume you are saying that $X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent?

Comment: @Math1000 Indeed. The reason is the same: the set $\{\omega\}$ belongs to both $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$, and $\mathsf{P}(\{\omega\}\cap \{\omega\})\ne \mathsf{P}(\{\omega\})^2$.

Comment: Right, so we cannot have $\mathbb P(X\in A,Y\in B)=\mathbb P(X\in A)\mathbb P(Y\in B)$ where for all $A\in\sigma(A)$ and $B\in\sigma(Y)$, which is the condition for independence.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, except that $A$ and $B$ in your notation are Borel sets, so they cannot belong to $2^{\Omega}$. Anyway, by definition $X$ and $Y$ are independent if the $\sigma$-fields that they generate are indepednent.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke there. We cannot have $\mathbb P(X\in A, Y\in B)=\mathbb P(X\in A)\mathbb P(Y\in B)$ for arbitrary Borel sets $A$ and $B$, since for some $A$ and $B$, we have $X^{-1}(A) = Y^{-1}(B) = \{\omega\}$.

Comment: I think we are all saying the same things in different ways

Answer (score -1):

I think, as I wrote in the comment, that the proposed solution from the OP, after the changes he made, is correct. Here I propose my approach, which is based on conditional probabilities,  that maybe shows a different point of view. I try to be a bit heavy with the notation to make the argument clearer.

We can consider $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, with probabilities $p_1,..p_5$, as sample space.

Let $X$,$Y$ two generic random variables, so that $X(i)=x_i$ and $Y(i)=y_i$. We observe that we can define $Z=(X,Y)$ so that:

$Z(i)=(x_i,y_i)$

It is clear than that:

$p(\{X=x_i\} \cap \{Y=y_k\})=p(Z=(x_i,y_k))=\delta_{i,k}p_i$ [1],

because if $i$ is not equal to $k$, $(x_i,y_k)$ does not belong to the codomain of $Z$. If $i$ is equal $k$ than the event $\{X=x_i\}$ happens only for $\omega \in \Omega=i$, for which $Y$ will be automatically equal to $y_i$. Thus the probability in [1] is simply $p_i$.

Using [1], $p(X=x_i|Y=y_k)=\frac{p(\{X=x_i\} \cap \{Y=y_k\})}{p(Y=y_k)}=\delta_{i,k}$ [2]

, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker symbol. If the two variables were independent [1] could be factored and we would obtain $p(X=x_i|Y=y_k)=p_i$.

Therefore the two variables cannot be independent. In fact given the value of $Y$ one can reconstruct in a unique way the value of X and viceversa (this is the interpretation of [2]: when conditioned on the value of $Y$, $X$ becomes deterministic). Told another way the value of X is highly "correlated" with the value of Y.

Comment: Why voting down? Is it because the solution is wrong? Please add comments if this is the case so that I can correct/remove...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see how you conclude that $$\frac{\mathbb P(\{X=x_i\}\cap\{Y=Y_k\})}{\mathbb P(Y=y_k)} = \delta_{i,k}. $$
After all, this expression depends on neither $p_i$ nor $p_k$.

Comment: It is a conditional probability. If Y is equal to yk we know that we selected the sample indexed by k (because all other samples give different y values). This implies than that X is equal to xk with probability one.

Comment: Maybe it was not clear that yk and xk are the values of Y and X on the sample indexed by k?

Comment: I think what you just said is different from what you wrote. But I agree that two random variables $X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent on this space; I am just not sure how to show it.

Comment: Today I am going to formalize better my answer so you can valuate better it's correctness...

Comment: Done. Is the new version better? I tried to define an auxiliary variable $Z$ to make the argument clearer...